# list in jQuery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I want to add a link in List but I'm creating list dynamically. When I click the list item, it display the detail view. For example

[image]

When I click land end it goes to detail of lands then I click coupon ,it goes to particular page, but I want set a link for save and email then I want to place the name which is in that image?

```
listItem.innerHTML = "<img src='" + image + "' class='ui-li-icon' style='height:20px; width:20px;'></img> <a href='#'  data-role='button' id='" + i + "' data-theme ='c' rel='external' data-inline='true' style='margin-left:1.5em; margin-top:2px;' ><font size='2' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'>" + prodName[i] + "</font></a>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not execute javascript that are placed on the ajax retrieved pages, as jquery mobile is not designed for that purpose, but you can use it's event system that will help you http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/api/events.html